# Django model pre_save Validation in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Following is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, 
verbose_name='Product title')
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, 
verbose_name='Product description')
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity')
    product_mrp = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Maximum retail price')
    product_offer_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Selling price')

def validate_produce_offer_price(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.product_offer_price > instance.product_mrp:
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        raise ValidationError('Product offer price cannot be greater than 
Product MRP.')


pre_save.connect(validate_produce_offer_price, sender=Product)
```

I am trying to validate the **product_offer_price** before the model is saved. The Validation error is being raised successfully, but the on an exception page created by the debugger. How to show the error on the form in the admin itself like other errors raised by the admin form?

[image: exception raised during changing the existing data]
[image: Exception raised while adding new data]

Comment: Did a lot of changes in answer, now you can try go with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, 
verbose_name='Product title')
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, 
verbose_name='Product description')
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity')
    product_mrp = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Maximum retail price')
    product_offer_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Selling price')
```

## forms.py

```
from models import Product
from django import forms

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = [id, ]

    def clean(self):
        product_offer_price = self.cleaned_data.get('product_offer_price')
        product_mrp = self.cleaned_data.get('product_mrp')
        if product_offer_price > product_mrp:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Product offer price cannot be greater than Product MRP.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from forms import ProductForm
from models import Product

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductForm
    list_display = ('product_title', 'product_description', 'product_qty', 'product_mrp', 'product_offer_price')

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: In the ProductForm, class Meta do we need to add "fields"?

Comment: @GautamMandewalker updated, there you can use fields/exclude

Comment: **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form ProductForm needs updating.**  I added "fields" and all works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatly the django-import-export skips this validation. Any tips how to apply for imports too?

Comment: @GautamMandewalker next time better say about admin-integrated libs in question text :) need time to browse lib

Comment: @GautamMandewalker I think you can create new question for that with extra tag 'django-import-export'

Comment: I posted here :). [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039898/how-to-do-field-validation-in-django-import-export). When you are free please have a look.