# How to do field validation in django-import-export

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

Following is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, 
verbose_name='Product title')
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, 
verbose_name='Product description')
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity')
    product_mrp = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Maximum retail price')
    product_offer_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Selling price')
```

I wanted to have a validation for **product_offer_price** field before save for which I had posted a **[QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038262/django-model-pre-save-validation-in-admin/46038327)** and it was answered with the working solution.

Validation needed is:

```
 if product_offer_price > product_mrp:
    raise ValidationError
```

Now the solution to above question works perfectly for the admin forms.

But, I have implemented django-import-export, in which I am importing Product Data in bulk in admin, and I need similar validation during bulk import.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is it typo there? In pre-raise spaces? 8 instead 4 )

Comment: Yes, corrected. I am just trying to give an example of what validation is needed and on which field.

Comment: Do the validation in your model's `clean()` method. That should cover both, validation from admin-site and validation from any views. If you have no `clean()` method, create and overwrite one - `clean()` is a super-method to all of your models.

Comment: @GautamMandewalker Check answer )

Comment: yes testing that on my app. Will update in sometime.

Comment: @MaxM With clean() method I have tried, it skips the validation in clean() method, but admin form based submissions work nicely, there is no need of having a separate forms.py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here was a little research process.

And finally I got it.

The trouble is avoiding ProductForm in import-export library.
Inside library import invoke method save() of instance, but if we raise ValidationError in Model (not in Form) = 500 with DEBUG = False, and traceback page with DEBUG = True.
So we should use "before_import" method in import_export Resource and "clean" method in django.forms Form.

## admin.py

```
from forms import ProductForm
from models import Product
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from django.forms import ValidationError

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        for row in dataset:
            if int(row[4]) < int(row[5]):
                raise ValidationError('Product offer price cannot be greater than Product MRP. '
                                      'Error in row with id = %s' % row[0])


class ProductAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product_title', 'product_description', 'product_qty', 'product_mrp', 'product_offer_price')
    form = ProductForm
    resource_class = ProductResource


admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import Product


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = [id, ]

    def clean(self):
        product_offer_price = self.cleaned_data.get('product_offer_price')
        product_mrp = self.cleaned_data.get('product_mrp')
        if product_offer_price > product_mrp:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Product offer price cannot be greater than Product MRP.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name='Product title')
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Product description')
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity')
    product_mrp = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Maximum retail price')
    product_offer_price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Selling price')
```

Comment: This works with a new project and app, but fails with my existing app. I don't understand why. The validation completely gets skipped like before in existing app. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way might be to hook into the import/export workflow by adding a custom `before_import_row` method to your resource class:

```py
class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        if int(row[4]) < int(row[5]):
            raise ValidationError('Product offer price cannot be greater than Product MRP. '
                                  'Error in row with id = %s' % row[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

here is another Simple Way For Django Rest Framework

```
def importcsv(request, company):
        for row in dataset['company']:
            if(row != company):
            raise PermissionDenied("You do not have permission to Enter Clients in Other Company, Be Careful")
```